# Apache is not working

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, webserver

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS. I have a virtual hosts on my server.

My .conf file :-

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin kamaldeep@kamaldeep.ddns.net
    ServerName 10.0.0.121
    ServerAlias 10.0.0.121
    DocumentRoot /files/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But when I enter 10.0.0.121 it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZZB8.png).
I don't know what  is causing this.

My Apache error log :-

```
[Fri Jul 01 15:13:05.160046 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2262:tid 3074648704] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations<br>
[Fri Jul 01 15:13:05.160478 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2262:tid 3074648704] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'<br>
[Fri Jul 01 15:23:18.475415 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2262:tid 3074648704] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down<br>
[Fri Jul 01 15:23:19.650003 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2559:tid 3075447424] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations<br>
[Fri Jul 01 15:23:19.650467 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2559:tid 3075447424] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'<br>
[Fri Jul 01 15:23:35.266006 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 2562:tid 2954832704] [client 10.0.0.7:50516] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/<br>
[Fri Jul 01 16:10:04.823455 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 2562:tid 2938047296] [client 10.0.0.7:50674] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:04:51.186287 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 2562:tid 2929654592] [client 10.0.0.7:51929] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:04:51.480669 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 2562:tid 3021974336] [client 10.0.0.7:51929] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://10.0.0.121/<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:16:31.446780 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2559:tid 3075447424] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:16:32.617721 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3151:tid 3074488960] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:16:32.618108 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3151:tid 3074488960] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:16:43.780175 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 3153:tid 3062889280] [client 10.0.0.7:52182] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/<br>
[Fri Jul 01 17:16:44.084861 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 3153:tid 3054496576] [client 10.0.0.7:52182] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /files/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://10.0.0.121/
```

Comment: PS - I have used this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must allow access to `/files/html`, with something like

```
<Directory /files/html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

By default, access is only granted to `/var/www`.